# How to use extern "C" dll function taking char** as an argument in C# application?

Tags: c#, c++, c, dll, unmanaged

I have dll with function:

```
extern "C"
int
doJob(char** buffer);
```

Its usage with C++ looks like this:

```
char* buf;
int status = doJob(&buf);
```

What definition should I have for this function in C#?
How can I use this function in C#?

Comment: Google easily brings many answers, like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26thfadc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...

Comment: It can have multiple signatures, depending on what you want to do with it. The problem is who will write on `buffer`, the calling function or the `doJob`?

Comment: Main question is not about how to use C dll in C# - with simple use cases I know how to do this:

Comment: [DllImport("containsdojob.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static extern Int32 doJob(out string buffer);

Comment: But what should be instead of "out string buffer"? With such case I have an exception.

Comment: Buffer will create doJob, using malloc or new.

Comment: @Sviatoslav Because you can't do it that way.

Comment: @Sviatoslav As Yoda you speak... Object does subject you do (*Buffer will create doJob*)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298268/returning-a-string-from-pinvoke

Comment: `extern "C"` is not a C issue, but a C++. So please remove the C tag.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible patterns is:

```
[DllImport("containsdojob.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Int32 doJob(out IntPtr buffer);

[DllImport("containsdojob.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void freeMemory(IntPtr buffer);
```

and

```
IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
string str = null;

try
{
    doJob(out buffer);

    if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer);
    }
}
finally
{
    if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        freeMemory(buffer);
    }
}
```

Note that you'll need a `freeMemory` method to free the memory allocated by `doJob`.

There are other possible patterns, for example based on `BSTR` and `SysAllocString` that are easier to implement C#-side (but more difficult to implement C-side)

The "pattern" for using BSTR:

C-side:

```
char *str = "Foo"; // your string
int len = strlen(str);
int wslen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str, len, 0, 0);
BSTR bstr = SysAllocStringLen(NULL, wslen);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str, len, bstr, wslen);
// bstr is the returned string
```

C#-side:

```
[DllImport("containsdojob.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Int32 doJob([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out string buffer);

string str;
doJob(out str);
```

The memory is automatically handled (freed) by the CLR.

If you are using Visual C++ you can even

```
char *str = "Foo"; // your string
_bstr_t bstrt(str);
BSTR bstr = bstrt.Detach(); 
// bstr is the returned string
```

Or C-side you could use one of the two allocators that can be freed C#-side: [LocalAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366723.aspx) or [CoTaskMemAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
char *str = "Foo"; // your string
char *buf = (char*)LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, strlen(str) + 1);
// or char *buf = (char*)CoTaskMemAlloc(strlen(str) + 1);
strcpy(buf, str);
// buf is the returned string
```

Then you use the first example, but instead of calling

```
freeMemory(buffer);
```

you call:

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer); // for LocalAlloc
```

or

```
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buffer); // for CoTaskMemAlloc
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me - it works now! By the way, "freeMemory" also exists in the same dll.

Comment: I used first method - with IntPtr.