# P/Invoke and .NET Target Framework

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

This issue is driving me up the wall... Just saying.

My company has a legacy C++ library and I have been tasked to create a .NET wrapper.
I have no experience of C++ or P/Invoke so to start with I am trying a simple method.

I have read the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke) and I have also found [a nice tutorial](https://manski.net/2012/05/pinvoke-tutorial-basics-part-1/).
However, I have discovered that the target .NET framework of the consuming app makes a difference.
The P/Invoke code from the tutorial works fine but I have noticed that he is targeting **.NET Framework 4 Client Profile**.
If I place break points then they are hit and everything works as expected, if I target a framework higher than 4 then the program crashes without exception.

I have a really simple method defined in C++:
`framework.h`

```cpp
extern "C" {
    API char* SayHello();
}
```

`dllmain.cpp`

```cpp
char* SayHello() {
    return (char*)"Hello";
}
```

`C#`

```cs
        [DllImport("PInvokeTest.dll")]
        public static extern string SayHello();
```

(I have tried setting CallingConvention and CharSet on the attribute in different combinations, I have managed to get Chinese characters, but nothing working higher than Framework 4)

My C++ project has `API=__declspec(dllexport)` it Preprocessor Definitions set and Calling Convention is `_stdcall (\Gz)` (I have also tried _cdecl).
The C# project works fine on **Framework 4**, when I change to anything above that then it just exits without exception.
I have also found [Dependencies GUI](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) that is showing me that `SayHello` is indeed there.

Our company uses 4.6.1, I also came across [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ceaa0911-a305-40c2-8916-e7d6d9daa429/pinvoke-net-4-vs-35?forum=vbgeneral) which lead me to [PInvokeStackImbalance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/netfx40-pinvokestackresilience-element?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but that doesn't do anything in my case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I could create a temp GitHub repo if needed.

Comment: `char*` is definitely not `C#`'s `string`. Not sure how it could work fine in any situation. You'll need to write a wrapper from ASCII C-style string to `C#`'s string manually.

Comment: @ALX23z Thank you for your comment - How do I write a wrapper from `char*` to string? As I say I have no experience. Thanks

Comment: Add attribute `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`

Comment: Ahhh, okay, thank you - If I knew it was a string issue then I might of done more research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I know it is a string issue I did a little searching and I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298268/returning-a-string-from-pinvoke).
So in the end I used the `BSTR` approach.

```cpp
BSTR SayHello() {
    return ::SysAllocString(L"Hello");
}
```

```cs
        [DllImport("DBReplicator.Lib.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public static extern string SayHello();
```

... Still don't know how I managed to get Chinese characters though.

Comment: `BSTR` support the full Unicode range.

Comment: Some time ago I had prepared a full-samples solution about marshalling strings between C/C++ and C#, both for .NET and .NET Framework... The samples are wholly undocumented, but quite complete. You can take a look at https://github.com/xanatos/CSharpCPlusPlusInteropSamples