# How to convert some C++ method to C# call?

Tags: c#, c++

I have a C++ dll that contains this method in the header (C++ code):

```
   enum Error
   {
          Error1,
          Error2,
          Error3,
   }

   void foo(const char* str, Error &err) ;
```

I am trying to call this method using a DllImport attribute but with no success. 
All other methods on this dll I can call with no problem.

On the DllImport I converted foo method to this:

```
   enum Error
   {
          Error1,
          Error2,
          Error3,
   }

   [DllImport("dll_name.dll")]
   public static extern void foo(string str, ref Error err);
```

but this isn't working either. 
I've also tried to use 'MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)' on the string and tried to change the 'CharSet' on the dllImport attribute => but nothing works

Comment: What does "no success" mean?  An error message?  Invalid results?

Comment: Exception ... no ability to call this method ... but from C++ code i can call this method with no problem

Comment: What exception do you get?  And what does `foo` do?  Does it try to modify the string that's passed in?

Comment: Take a look at [how to marshall char*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162897/marshal-char-in-c-sharp). You might want to use LPCTSTR instead of const char*.

Comment: the string is const ... can't change it .. i don't know what foo do internal.

Comment: bokibeg ... please read the question. i already try to change the CharSet

Comment: Could the problem be in the 2nd parameter?  Perhaps just make it a uint to see if it works:  "public static extern foo(string str, ref uint err);"

Comment: Are you sure the 'foo' function is visible externally? Can you see it in a tool like 'depends.exe'? [http://www.dependencywalker.com/]

Comment: yes, visible . other methods are work fine

Comment: @Yanshof are you sure that the issue lies in the string paramater

Comment: What is the exact exception message?  "no ability to call this method" is not it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this, I notice the lack of the void.

```
enum Error
{
      Error1,
      Error2,
      Error3,
}

[DllImport("dll_name.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void foo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str, ref Error err);
```

I would also make sure the method is visible in your application. Noted by karmasponge

EDIT: You can try changing calling convention. If the exception you get is a StackImbalance, this should fix the issue.

Comment: try already ... nothing work. the method is visible - this is not problem if visibility